# ExecuteStoredProcedure throws error code 17004

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using these libraries

```
import org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.NativeJdbcExtractor;
```

and this class

```
CallableStatementCreatorFactory
```

Detailed exception

```
Root Cause: [org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call xxxxxxxxxxxx()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid coloumn: 16; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid coloumn: 16]</faultstring>

Map<String, Object> result = QueryExecutor.getInstance().executeStoredProcedure("XXX", null);
```

Did not understand the main reason why we get this error ?

Comment: Show the stored procedure please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your function returns a `BOOLEAN` value.  The [Oracle JDBC driver does not support `BOOLEAN` values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28928).

The following class reproduces a similar error:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class Error17004Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "user", "password")) {

            try (Statement stmt = c.createStatement()) {
                stmt.execute(
                    "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bool_test RETURN BOOLEAN " +
                    "AS BEGIN RETURN TRUE; END;");
            }

            try (CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall("{ ? = call bool_test }")) {
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN);
                cstmt.execute();
                System.out.println("Got result of " + cstmt.getObject(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Got a SQLException with message '" + e.getMessage() +
                    "' and error code " + e.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Got a SQLException with message 'Invalid column type: 16' and error code 17004
```

Fortunately there's an easy workaround: wrap your function in a call to `sys.diutil.bool_to_int`.  `sys.diutil.bool_to_int` converts the `BOOLEAN` values `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL` to `1`, `0` and `NULL` respectively.  Then you just have to read an integer value from the stored procedure call instead of a boolean.  Of course, you then have to do the conversion between the integer value returned and the boolean value you probably wanted, but that should be straightforward.

If I take my class above and replace the two lines

```
            try (CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall("{ ? = call bool_test }")) {
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN);
```

with

```
            try (CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall(
                    "{ ? = call sys.diutil.bool_to_int(bool_test) }")) {
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
```

and run my class again, I get the following output:

```
Got result of 1
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is no mismatch between the datatypes and make sure that there are no null values or constraints.

Comment: Where should I expect the mismatch? Inside my store procedure or my call method ? * Also we know that other plSql is working

Comment: In your call method. Did you add some parameters to the procedure? Also check if the procedure does not returning any null values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The procedure is returning boolean. There are no input parameters

Comment: Basicaly I thought about datatypes and some constraints in your DB because of the _Invalid coloumn_ Error. But with the new information it doesnt make any sense anymore :) Do you get some new ideas whats going wrong?